# How to setup ci/cd pipeline for github, docker dev and prod environments via concourse?

Tags: docker, github, concourse

I am actually setting up CI/CD pipeline between GitHub, concourse, docker.
here i am able get the code into concourse and build the docker images and push those images to docker private registry.

After build success i want to deploy those images to dev and prod environments via concourse.

How can i achieve this?

I want everything should be triggered from concourse. we should not connect to dev, prod and run bash scripts manually for updating running containers with the latest iamges from docker private registry.

Please send me the links if you are maintaining dev, pro environments as i expected. thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what it is you're asking and showing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you already know how your pipeline should be organized. You should be able to do it using the `git-resource`, `docker-image-resource` and concourse jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to figure out how to do this with Concourse, but solved it with a Linux-script.  It is possible to run a script inside the Docker container, specified in the Concourse build-plan, for instance like this:

```
  run:
    dir: build-dir
    path: sh
    user: root
    args:
      - -exc
      - |
        ./gradlew build
        scp build/lib/app.jar deploy@production.env:<install-loc>
```